# React Native different categories rendered to header component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a React Native quiz application. I already have developed the header component and it looks fantastic.

```
// import libraries for making a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

// make a component
const Header = (props) => {
  const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>;
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
};

// make a component available to other parts of the app
export default Header;
```

I am going to be doing an ajax request to an api that has a category and then one quiz question per category.

When I make a GET request to this endpoint I get back an array of objects and each object has a question category and one boolean question of true or false.

So in total I have 10 categories with a question for each category for a total of 10 questions.

So I need to figure out how to make an Ajax request or an http request from my mobile application to fetch this list of data and more critically, once I have the list of data, I need to figure out a way to get the category piece to render as the header.

This is the part I am stuck on.

I plan to have a component called `QuestionList`, the purpose of `QuestionList` will be to fetch the list of data or fetch the list of questions and once fetched, it will render several `QuestionDetail` components. So I will have a `QuestionList` and a `QuestionDetail`.

But again the api has a category for each question and I want to render that category content as the header for each question. So a different header each time the user goes to the next question.

So in the code above, rather than letting the header component decide what text should be displayed I refactored it slightly so that the app component will decide what text to show in there.

Did I just mess this up in terms of what I am trying to accomplish? Should I have let the header component decide what text should be displayed? And more importantly how do I get the `header` component or the `App` component to render the different categories? Should I be creating a separate `CategoryList` component and then a `CategoryHeader` component for each specific component that renders a different category from the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements you need a [`SectionList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html).

It already has a support for `renderSectionHeader` where you can integrate your `Header` component

An example to that would be

```
<SectionList 
  renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => <QuestionDetails {...item} />} // Render your Question Details Component here
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => <Header {...title}/>} //... Render your Custom Header Component here 
  sections={[ 
   { title: 'Category1', data: ['question1', 'question2'] }, 
   { title: 'Category2', data: ['question1', 'question2'] }, 
   { title: 'Category3', data: ['question1', 'question2'] }, 
   ]} 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index} />
```

*This is just a sample, you can modify to generate the array based on this that suits your requirements.*